# Validation user message not showing

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-form, validation, list-validation

I have a formula in List settings-> validation settings.

The formula validates correctly. The user message  I entered does not display, it displays its own message below which is

> Error: The validation formula has evaluated to an error.

How can I show my User message?

See a screenshot below:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: The output is:                                                                                                             Error: The validation formula has evaluated to an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue in my environment. I haven’t found other formulas that block the custom user message but at least **DATEDIF** function is doing that.

You can switch to another formula like

```
[Original planned end date]>=[Actual start date]
```

or

```
[Original planned end date]-[Actual start date]>=0
```

It functions the same in this scenario.

[image]

Comment: Yes have changed the formula slightly and boom it works, message appears. Thank you.

Comment: For the message 'End date must be greater than start date' this appears at the top of my form. Can the message be moved to the field which has the validation?

Comment: @Tony I'm afraid not. That is the default behavior for list validation, and it cannot be modified.

Comment: @Tony Is there anything more we can help you with? Would you please give it a vote or accept it as answer if you find the reply helpful?

Comment: Ok done have marked as complete. Thank you

Comment: @Chelsea_MSFT - I also have this issue where my custom user message is not being displayed, it only displays `Error: The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again`.  Is this some sort of 'known issue'?  Specific details and steps to reproduce are in my question here:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/307172