# Microsoft List validation not working in SharePoint Online - Error: The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, error, calculated-column-formula, list-validation

I have a SharePoint Online List.

It has some fields that are 'Required' fields.

I am also trying to use List Validation so that:

- IF the value of `MyChoiceColumn` is `Yes`
- THEN the `AdditionalInformation` text field requires a value

`MyChoiceColumn` is a `Choice` field with two values - `Yes` and `No`.

`AdditionalInformation` is a `Single Line of Text` column.

I have entered this formula into `List Settings` > `Validation`:

```
=IF(MyChoiceColumn="Yes",IF(ISBLANK([Additional Information]),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

*(note: the space in `[Additional Information]` is intentional and correct)*

The formula syntax looks correct to me and I have seen the same syntax [demonstrated here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/292541).

When I try and submit the form, it shows this error at the very TOP of the form:

[image]

The user message that I have entered in the list validation settings is not displayed.

The form also produces some quirky behaviour where a required Date field 'date picker' is automatically opened (even though a date was chosen prior to trying to submit the form).

**Steps To Reproduce**

- Create a Microsoft List
- Add a Date column named `MyDateColumn` and make it a required field
- Add a Choice column named `MyChoiceColumn` with two values - `Yes` and `No`
- Add a Single Line of Text column named `AdditionalInformation`
- Rename the `AdditionalInformation` column so it has a space, i.e `Additional Information`
- Go to List settings > Validation settings
- Enter this formula:

```
=IF(MyChoiceColumn="Yes",IF([Additional Information]="",FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

OR this formula:

```
=IF(MyChoiceColumn="Yes",IF(ISBLANK([Additional Information]),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

- Enter this custom user message:

You have selected a response that requires further information be entered into this form

- Save those settings
- Go to the frontend of the form
- Enter a date in the required date field
- Select `Yes` in the `MyChoiceColumn` column
- Leave the `Additional Information` blank
- Click `Save` to submit the form

The following things happen:

- My custom error message is not displayed
- This error is displayed at the very top of the form:

> Error: The server was unable to save the form at this time.
> Please try again

- The data picker for the Date column pops open

This is what should be happening:

- The form displays my custom error message in a position that is relevant to where the error is occurring OR at the bottom of the form near the `Save` button

Comment: Seems like generic error message. Maybe temporary issue from Microsoft's end. I will try to reproduce and get back to you.

Comment: Not sure if you have seen my reply in comments section of answer by another user (it is deleted now). I want to thank you for the kind words and I am very happy to hear that my answers are helping you and your colleagues. Let's connect via [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/ganeshsanap) or [Blog contact page](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/contact/) (Anonymous/Personal chat) if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed the steps provided by you and I am able to reproduce this issue.

I have tried creating multiple lists and using different list validation formula with different "User Messages". But I am still receiving same error message mentioned by you in all the scenarios.

I think this is a temporary issue from Microsoft's end. I will suggest you to raise a support ticket with Microsoft directly and report this issue.

Follow documentation for same: [Get M365 support - online support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support)

Comment: Thank you very much for reproducing the issue, I submitted a support ticket around the same time I posted the original question, and the issue is still occurring, as soon as I get a resolution from Microsoft I will post back.

Comment: sure, thank you.

Comment: Did you get any update from Microsoft support related to this issue?

Comment: They have said it is a worldwide issue that custom validation messages are not showing but they have not provided a solution or fix yet, I am still getting the same behaviour.

Comment: Yesterday I read somewhere few users saying this issue is fixed for them now.

Comment: Also, I have started accepting "Buy me a coffee" support: https://ko-fi.com/ganeshsanap. This link is now available on my blog site as well at the right hand side bar on the blog pages. 

Comment: They said there was a fix for it on March 30th, but I have just tested and still getting the same behaviour.  In regards to "Buy me a coffee" link, thank you - and for reference for everyone else, I made a query about it, Ganesh is not spamming :)

Comment: I guess we have to wait until Microsoft fixes it completely and rollout the new update on all SharePoint tenants.

Comment: I just tested it on my SharePoint site and it is showing the custom message for me (Note: I am using targeted release tenant). Also, others confirmed it is working for them as well at: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/error-quot-the-server-was-unable-to-save-the-form-at-this-time/m-p/3800620#M70291. Try removing and re-adding the formula & user message once to check if it works.

Comment: I tried removing formula and message, saving, then re-adding, saving, clearing cache and reloading list.  now the correct message is displaying, but it is still opening up the date picker field calendar for no reason (it already had a value selected).  the end-user will think there is something wrong with the date picker field value when there is not.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue.

**When I enter this validation:**

```
=IF(Status="New",FALSE)
```

The error message is "Error: The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again."

I want the custom message to appear.

**If I enter this validation:**

```
=IF(Status="New",TRUE)
```

There is no error message and it saves correctly.